# redirect user to a specific page with rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1

I use devise and i need redirect a user to specific page `if seller_disabled_paypal_permissions != nil` from my `application_controller.rb`

I have this code on my application_controller.rb

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_filter :bad_sellers
 #more code
 .
 .
 .
 private
   def bad_sellers
    if user_signed_in?
     redirect_to requirements_to_sell_user_path, :alert => t('.error') if current_user.seller_disabled_paypal_permissions != nil
     return false
    end
   end
end
```

But I get error:

**Error 310 (net::ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS): There were too many redirects.**

**How can I do it?**

Comment: Look at your logs and see where all the redirects are coming from.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix to the problem:

On `applicatio_controller.rb`

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 protect_from_forgery
 before_filter :bad_sellers
 #code here
 #code here
 def bad_sellers
  if user_signed_in? && !(current_user.seller_disabled_paypal_permissions.nil?)
   redirect_to requirements_to_sell_user_path(current_user), :alert => t('.error')
  end
 end
end
```

On `users_controllers.rb` (`users_controllers` is child of `application_controller`)

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
 skip_before_filter :bad_sellers, :only => [:requirements_to_sell] #parent filter on application_controller.rb

 def requirements_to_sell
  #more code
  #more code
 end

end
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private
   def bad_sellers
    if user_signed_in? && !(current_user.seller_disabled_paypal_permissions.nil?)
     redirect_to root_path, :alert => t('.error')
    end
   end
```

I've never explicitly returned any value from a `before_fiter` so that's my first guess.

Your problem is that you've created this behavior on `ApplicationController` and I am wagering that your root path is also a controller that inherits from `ApplicationController` therefore its placing you into an infinite redirect loop.

You'll need something like:

```
before_filter :bad_sellers, :except => [:whatever_your_root_path_action_is]
```

Comment: Thank you, if I call to this method, the code does not work. I have tried call to this method with a before_filter but I get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

When you have a conditional redirect, you would want to use `return` so rails doesn't see any other redirects (not sure how to put it better than that).

as per your example:

```
def bad_sellers
  if user_signed_in?
    if !current_user.seller_disabled_paypal_permissions.nil?
      return redirect_to root_path, :alert => t('.error')
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: The same problem, How can I call to this method? Thank you

Comment: did you try the method after I edited it? I took out the extra return false at the end. otherwise I am not sure what could be happening. the before_filter is firing, right? maybe take this out of your private block

Comment: If I make the redirect to "http://www.google.com" is does work fine. I don't understand why I can with a redirect to external page, but If I try a redirect inside app, I get the error!

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it may be recursive.  Does root_path also call this before filter?  You would want to find a way not to call this in that case.  Look into `skip_before_filter`

Also, you don't need to 'return false'.

Comment: If I run `skip_before_filter`, the method `bad_sellers` is not called. Then, the user can browsing through the application. I want redirect a specific page to the user `if current_user.seller_disabled_paypal_permissions != nil`. Thank you!

Comment: I think you want to skip before filter on the root page.  If this is the page you redirect to, you don't need to check for bad_sellers there.

Comment: root page is a example, I need redirect to other page. I want to force the user to go to `requirements_to_sell_user_path`. I have modified the question. Thank you

Comment: @hyperrjas - Is this action under ApplicationController?  If so, it'll try to redirect to itself and cause the error you're seeing.  With skip_before_filter on that action, you will not redirect.  It's likely you have a few actions that you do not want to redirect from.